# c++ secondary dependency resolution with runpath

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, rpath

I have the following problem:

I am trying to build software on an Ubuntu18 by using the default gnu compiler (gcc-7) and linker versions available.

Now we have the case, that an executable may link a shared library, which again links another shared libraries. Thus the executable has a secondary dependency. But secondary dependencies are only picked up from rpath and not from runpath. So even if the secondary dependency is placed in the runpath folder of the executable it will not be found.

The problem was identified when using googletest in combination with cmake. There the tests cannot be compiled, because of not found secondary dependencies. So setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` might not be an option or at least complicates everything a lot.

**Here is an example for what is going wrong with gcc-7 on an Ubuntu18 system (but works fine with gcc-5 on Ubuntu16):**

**secondary.hpp**

```cpp
#include <string>

class World{
    public:
        std::string world();
};
```

**secondary.cpp**

```cpp
#include "secondary.hpp"

std::string World::world(){
    return "world";
}
```

**primary.hpp**

```cpp
#include <string>

class Hello{
  public:
    std::string helloWorld();
};
```

**primary.cpp**

```cpp
#include "primary.hpp"
#include "secondary.hpp"
#include <sstream>

std::string Hello::helloWorld(){
    std::stringstream strm;
    World world;

    strm << "hello ";
    strm << world.world();
    strm << "!";

    return strm.str();
}
```

and compile the both libraries like this

```sh
mkdir build
cd build
gcc -shared -o libsecondary.so -fPIC ../secondary.cpp
gcc -shared -o libprimary.so -fPIC ../primary.cpp  -lsecondary -L$(pwd)
```

If I now build an executable from the following files

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "primary.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Hello hello;
    std::cout << hello.helloWorld() << std::endl;
}
```

by doing the following in a new build directory (parallel to the previous one)

```sh
cd ..
mkdir build_app
cd build_app
gcc -o app ../main.cpp -L../build -lstdc++ -lsecondary -lprimary  -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)/../build
```

If I now do `ldd app` I see, that `libsecondary.so` is not found

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0cf8c000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9e86fe7000)
    libprimary.so => <some_path>/libprimary.so (0x00007f9e86de5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9e86bcd000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9e867dc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9e8643e000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9e87573000)
    libsecondary.so => not found
```

and the runpath of app is (by running `readelf -d app`)

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x1d40 contains 31 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libprimary.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath:[<some_path>/build]
```

The question is, why `ld` is not taking `libsecondary.so` from the runpath of `app`? Both `libprimary.so` and `libsecondary.so` are placed in the same folder, but only `libprimary.so` is found.

One solution to the problem is to compile with `--disable-new-dtags` which will use rpath instead of runpath and is the default for gcc-5 on Ubuntu16. However, the usage of rpath seems to be deprecated from ld.

So what is a proper way to use runpath together with secondary dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libprimary` is responsible for loading `libsecondary`, not `app`. That means that the DT_RUNPATH entry for `app` does not apply.

Since you have control over all libraries, you could add a `-Wl,-rpath=...` to the compile statements for `libprimary` and `libsecondary` as well.

Comment: It is true, that this could solve the problem. However, usually I can relocate libraries, so setting rpath (or runpath) for `libprimary` will only work unless I decide to relocate `libsecondary`. This is essentially true, if the library has been compiled on a different system (e.g. a CI pipeline)

I am still confused, that rpath is picking any library (also transitive ones) and runpath does not. Not sure, why the behavior is so different

Comment: **Edit** Actually this is the correct answer and also can be found in the manual of ld: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Comment: What if we do not have control over the libsecondary and it is a 3rd party library?

Comment: Please ask a new question (referencing this one) instead of commenting on a year-old question.

Comment: @Botje, any ideas if there is any situation when this rpath is added by the linker in the binaries automatically? Or is this required to always be manually set?

Comment: I know Cmake does this by default. No idea about others. Suggest you ask a new question about this if you're curious.