# Why my executable runs with `RPATH` but not with `RUNPATH`

Tags: c++, linker, rpath, runpath

I build an executable **`app`** that uses **`liba`**. **`liba`** in turn needs *`libb`*. *`libb`* in turn needs *`libc`*. The dependency looks like this: **`app`** -> **`liba`** -> *`libb`* -> *`libc`*. The **`app`** and **`liba`** are built by me while *`libb`* and *`libc`* are 3rd party. I do not know how they were compiled, but I know that they both are in the same folder and I have a CMake config to find *`libb`*.

---

### A setup that is not working.

In `CMake` I find the package for *`libb`*, publically link the lib to **`liba`** and finally link **`liba`** to **`app`**. The **`app`** compiles fine but running it I'm getting: `error while loading shared libraries: libc: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I.e. the last library, which symbols I don't even use directly can not be found.

I inspect my library **`liba`** with `readelf -d liba | grep PATH`:

```
...
0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/path/to/dir/with/both/libb/and/libc:]
...
```

So the path is inside my **`liba`**, it's correct and points to both *`libb`* and *`libc`*.

Next, I inspect the loading search paths with `LD_DEBUG=libs ./app`:

```
...
     27012: find library=libb [0]; searching
     27012:  search path=/*a lot of paths INCLUDING the needed path*/       (RUNPATH from file ./app)
...
     27012: find library=libc [0]; searching
     27012:  search cache=/etc/ld.so.cache
     27012:  search path=/*a lot of system paths, but the needed path is MISSING*/      (system search path)

     27012:   trying file=/lib/x86_64/libc
     many other tries
...
```

How can that be that *`libb`* is found in `RUNPATH` but *`libc`* not???! Why the *`libc`* uses `system search path` instead of `RUNPATH`??

---

### A setup that is working

Next, I try to use a `RPATH` when build my library **`liba`** by setting `-Wl,--disable-new-dtags` flag. Now `readelf -d liba | grep PATH` prints me the same path as before, but abbreviated with `RPATH` instead of `RUNPATH` and `LD_DEBUG=libs ./app` prints:

```
...
     27012: find library=libb [0]; searching
     27012:  search path=/*a lot of paths INCLUDING the needed path*/       (RUNPATH from file ./app)
...
     27012: find library=libc [0]; searching
     27012:  search path=/*a lot of paths INCLUDING the needed path*/       (RUNPATH from file ./app)
...
```

Now both libraries use `RUNPATH` but I can't understand why. Why the hell they use `RUNPATH` though the lib was compiled with explicit `RPATH`?? Where does this come from?

---

Update:

Here by `[libc]` I mean my 3rd party library (a, b, `c`), not the system one.

```
readelf -d libb | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_thread.so.1.65.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.65.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

Update 2:

After more reading, I was able to formulate the search request more precisely and immediately found the explanation. For example, here:

[c++ secondary dependency resolution with runpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248421/c-secondary-dependency-resolution-with-runpath)

[Dynamic linking with rpath not working under Ubuntu 17.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117443/dynamic-linking-with-rpath-not-working-under-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Can you dump your `libb`'s dependencies, this is probably a missing `DT_NEEDED` dependency in `libb`.

Comment: I updated the question. `libc` is listed in its dependencies.